# Show if a real matrix $X$ has real eigenvalues, then $X$ is similar over the reals to its Jordan canonical form.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is Brian Hall's lie algebra textbook:
[image]

I would like to ask what does the hint actually mean? When we say $X$ is similar over the reals, does it mean the change of basis matrix is all purely real? And can someone provide me a reference for the proof of this hint?

Comment: It means that all matrices have real entries, i.e. if $X=PJP^{-1}$ is a Jordan decomposition, then $P$ and $J$ have real entries. If you already know that $X$ can be written as $PJP^{-1}$ *over the complex numbers* (i.e. the algebraic closure of $\mathbb R$), then by assumption $J$ is real, and you can think about why $P$ is real (think about how one constructs $P$).

Comment: @Bill Yes, it means that the change of basis matrix is all purely real